# Youtube channel gadget development - How to contact Youtube tech producer?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

We're developing a Youtube gadget for a brand from Europe, and basically https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1727240?hl=en&ref_topic=4601817 states that:

> Before your gadget can appear on your channel, it needs to be reviewed
>   by YouTube. We recommend that you include a YouTube Tech Producer in
>   your process before starting development. When planning the
>   development for your channel, allow 3-5 business days for initial
>   review before development begins. We also require 3-5 business days
>   for final review, not including additional time required for any
>   changes.

There's just no way to get in touch with Youtube Tech Producer. We tried to phone Google, tried Youtube help forms, support forms - no one knows a thing, as if the doc is deprecated.

Does anybody know how to get in touch with Youtube so that we can setup the custom channel gadget?

Comment: We're facing exactly the same thing. Did you manage to find a way through? Thanks.

Comment: No. We never did, gave up trying.